Higher (BV) regularity of solutions to Poisson equation with Radon measure right-hand side?
I am trying to understand higher regularity for solutions to Poisson's equation when the right-hand side is a Radon measure. In particular:
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u = \mu \text{ in } \Omega\\
u = 0\text{ on }\partial\Omega
\end{cases}$$
I have two specific questions:

If $\mu$ is a Radon measure with finite total variation, is the Hessian $D^2 u$ a Radon measure?
If 1 is true, and $\mu$ has additional structure, say $\mu\ll\mathcal{H}^{d-1}$, does the Hessian inherit that structure?

What I know:
From Calderon-Zygmund, we know that $\mu\in L^p\implies Du\in W^{1,p}$ for $1<p<\infty$. It is well known that this estimate fails when $\mu\in L^1$.
The most comprehensive paper I can find about this is by Mingione [1]. The problem considered is more general (the operator is nonlinear elliptic), but specialising to the Laplacian case, the result is that $Du\in W_{\text{loc}}^{1-\epsilon,1}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ for every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. $\nabla u$ also shows BV-like behaviour in that its set of non-Lebesgue points has Hausdorff dimension less than or equal to $n-1$. In the referenced paper, after Corollary 1.7, the author makes the statement that the BV-like behaviour can be guessed by simply replacing $\Delta u$ with $D^2 u$ with some Heuristics. The paper goes a little further and considers measures $\mu$ that do not concentrate on low dimensional sets and gets better bounds on higher fractional derivatives.
Reference
[1] Mingione, Giuseppe. "The Calderón-Zygmund theory for elliptic problems with measure data" Annali della Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa-Classe di Scienze 6.2 (2007): 195-261, MR2352517, Zbl 1178.35168.

On a related topic.  Try using a duality proof to examine the case of $\mu$ finite total variation...also you can try a duality proof when $ d \mu = f(x) dx$ where $ \int_{\Omega} | f(x)| \delta(x) dx < \infty$ where $ \delta(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $ \partial \Omega$.

No, (1) is false. For a counterexample consider the fundamental solution of the Laplacian, which solves
$$ \Delta \Phi = \delta_0 \quad\text{in } \mathbb R^d.$$
Then $\mathrm{D}\Phi$, which can be computed explicitly, does not lie in $\mathrm{BV}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega;\mathbb R^d)$ when $d \geq 2$.
One way to see this is to note that $\lvert\mathrm{D}\Phi\rvert \simeq \lvert x \rvert^{-(d-1)}$ lies in $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$ if and only if $p < \frac{d}{d-1}$, whereas a $\mathrm{BV}$ function would embed into $L_{\mathrm{loc}}^{\frac{d}{d-1}}$.
Note that for a suitably regular domain $\Omega$ containing the origin, you can adapt this counterexample by solving
$$\begin{cases}
  \Delta v = 0 &\text{in } \Omega, \\ v = - \Phi &\text{on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}$$
and observe that $u = v + \Phi$ solves your original problem with $\mu = \delta_0$.
Since $v$ is regular (as $\Phi$ is smooth away from the origin), $u$ is as irregular as $\Phi$.

Thank you for the first observation, it opened my eyes because it is also in line with the usual results for elliptic equations with measures, that the solution is in $W^{1,p}$ for any $p<d/d-1$.
